# Using init and didSet with NSManaged objects

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have the following class, the objects are stored using CoreData

```
extension CDate{

  @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<CDate> {
      return NSFetchRequest<CDate>(entityName: "CDate")
  }

  @NSManaged public var day: Int
  @NSManaged public var month: Int

}
```

I need to add to it a property , this porperty will be updated every time the other properties will be changing:

```
  var date:DateComponent
```

This property needs to be initialised when creating the CDate Object. In regular class I would use init constructor to initialize the object and didSet{} on month and day to update the date property whenever month and day properties are updated.

How can I achieve that in this class when it can't have init and didSet{} ?

Comment: Core Data is heavily based on Objective-C key-value observing. Take advantage of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution for this would be creating a `computed-property` within `CDate` and its value would be computed during the time of execution and will get the updated value at any point of time.

```
extension CDate {
    var date: Date { 
        // compute the date and return here.
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume using a `computed-property` would give you your desired result.

Comment: Property change on day or month properties will trigger recalculation of date  ? date depends on the properties values.

Comment: The computed property will return the new value depending on changes you've made to the values related to it.